# How to run a function inside a event once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I have a function in Angular.js to determine if a user is inactive or active. When the user is active I want to execute a function after a certain time.

I have it working but the function is currently running in the same numbers as the executed events.
How can I ensure that this function is executed once each time?

```
.run(function($timeout, $document) {
    // console.log('starting run');

    // Timeout timer value
    var TimeOutTimerValue = 120000;

    // Start a timeout
    var TimeOutThread = $timeout(function() {
        LogoutByTimer();
    }, TimeOutTimerValue);
    var bodyElement = angular.element($document);

    angular.forEach(
        [
            'keydown',
            'keyup',
            'click',
            'mousemove',
            'DOMMouseScroll',
            'mousewheel',
            'mousedown',
            'touchstart',
            'touchmove',
            'scroll',
            'focus'
        ],
        function(EventName) {
            bodyElement.bind(EventName, function(e) {
                TimeOutResetter(e);
            });
        }
    );

    function LogoutByTimer() {
        console.log('Logout');
    }

    function TimeOutResetter(e) {
        console.log(' ' + e);

        $timeout(function() {
            console.log('run this once ');
        }, 2000);

        // Stop the pending timeout
        $timeout.cancel(TimeOutThread);

        // Reset the timeout
        TimeOutThread = $timeout(function() {
            LogoutByTimer();
        }, TimeOutTimerValue);
    }
})
```

It's going about the `console.log('run this once')` in the function `TimeOutResetter(e)`.
How to run that once?

[Click here to see it on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWtsXhsdi4ivrmix?preview)

Comment: i think the simple way is create a global var with value false, then create an if to the part you want run 1 time and see if is false and run it, when you run it change var to true so next time doesn't match with condition

Comment: yes that seems like a good one, let me try.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini no didn't work, tried like `var runOnce = false;

                $timeout(function() {

                    if (!runOnce) {
                        console.log('send session');
                    }

                    runOnce = true;
                }, 2000);`

Comment: If you want to implement the same behavior (running only once) for several functions in your source code, you may want to abstract the behavior into a wrapper function, enabling you to "onceify" any function on-the-fly, like `myFunctionOnce = once(myFunction)`. See: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a variable with a handle to the timeout to the outer scope. Then when you're about to start the timeout, you check whether this handle is defined. If not it gets to run.

Here's an example:

```js
app.run(function($rootScope, $timeout, $document) {    
    console.log('starting run');

    // Declare the handle
    var executeOnceTimeout;

    ...

    function TimeOut_Resetter(e){
        console.log(' ' + e);

        // Check if handle exists, if not continue.
        if (!executeOnceTimeout) {
            // Assign timeout-function to variable. 
            executeOnceTimeout = $timeout(function() {
                console.log('call this once');
            }, 2000);
        }
        ...
    }

})
```

#### Update

Based on the comments, it sounds like what you're looking for is for the "callOnce"-function to be throttled for a period of time, effectively meaning it can only be called once every X milliseconds.

That can be achieved with the above code by making the following change:

```
// Check if handle exists, if not continue.
if (!executeOnceTimeout) {
    // Assign timeout-function to variable. 
    executeOnceTimeout = $timeout(function() {
        // Do work
        console.log('call this once');
        // Reset callback, to enable it to be called again next time an event happens. 
        executeOnceTimeout = null;
    }, 2000);
}
```

[You can see it in action using this Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZE1RWJlMovisCmUs)

Comment: This execute the console log once, but it needs to be executed once again when the event take place again. Now it's only doing this once, but it needs to be repeated after each event.

Comment: When exactly do you want it to be reset? You can simply reassign the variable `executeOnceTimeout = null` whenever you need it reset, and it'll run again next time the `TimeOut_Resetter`-function is called.

Comment: What I want to do is that when you eg have `47 [object MouseEvent]` the function with log is showed once, after that then you have another event `17 [object MouseEvent]`, after this event I want to show the log once again, so after each event 1x the log/function.

Comment: You can add `executeOnceTimeout = null` to the end of the callOnce-function. What that does, is that everytime the callOnce-function has finished, it'll reset. Effectively, that means that the callOnce-function will at most be called every 2000ms. That effect is called Throttling. Is that what you're seeking?

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer to better reflect your intent.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with your plunk and work, see my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Application_TimeOut">
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<script>
var app = angular.module('Application_TimeOut', []);
app.run(function($rootScope, $timeout, $document) {    
    console.log('starting run');
    var runOnce = true;
    // Timeout timer value
    var TimeOutTimerValue = 5000;

    // Start a timeout
    var TimeOut_Thread = $timeout(function(){ LogoutByTimer() } , TimeOutTimerValue);
    var bodyElement = angular.element($document);
    
    angular.forEach(['keydown', 'keyup', 'click', 'mousemove', 'DOMMouseScroll', 'mousewheel', 'mousedown', 'touchstart', 'touchmove', 'scroll', 'focus'], 
    function(EventName) {
         bodyElement.bind(EventName, function (e) { TimeOut_Resetter(e) });  
    });

    function LogoutByTimer(){
        console.log('Logout');
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// redirect to another page(eg. Login.html) here
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    function TimeOut_Resetter(e){
        console.log(' ' + e);
        if(runOnce){
            runOnce = false;
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log('run this once');               
            }, 2000);            
        }
        
        /// Stop the pending timeout
        $timeout.cancel(TimeOut_Thread);

        /// Reset the timeout
        TimeOut_Thread = $timeout(function(){ LogoutByTimer() } , TimeOutTimerValue);
    }

})
</script>
</html>
```

I add `var runOnce = true;` at the top then add if before run your command and change it when it runned.

Comment: This execute the console log once, but it needs to be executed once again when the event take place again. Now it's only doing this once and it stops doing it again when the event take place again, but it needs to be repeated after each event once.

Comment: was simple, add true when logout.